# PHP fileatime -> Always 1 o'clock in the morning

Tags: php

I wrote a routine to delete all files in a folder that have not been used for the last x days.

I am using the function `fileatime()` 
*[or more precisely the DirectoryIterator function `getATime()` ]*

When debugging, I noticed that the last access time for all the files was 1 o'clock this morning.

This is the time when the server is automatically backed-up.

So the question is... 
How to find out the last time the file was accessed, by a user and not the automatic back up.

Any help would be appreciated.

David

Comment: If your filesystem is set to not record access times (mount option `noatime`), then there's no programmatic way for PHP to figure it out. Use stats file or db table to keep track then.

Comment: `filemtime()` instead ? A=access; M=modification

Comment: Thanks.  Thought of that too ust now.  My idea is that whenever a user accesses a file, I could rename that file to itself.  Have tried googling but could not determine of filemtime() considers a rename as a modification.  Any ideas?

Comment: would take less time to just test this than ask ;)

Comment: I wanted to be polite :-) Tested, filemtime does not recognize a rename as a modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with.
Whenever a user accesses a file, I copy the file to a new name and delete the older version.  This sets a new modification time.

Independently, in a separate routine, I look through all files in the folder and delete any folders that have not been accessed (modified) since X days.

```
function DeleteUnusedFiles($FolderName,$NumberOfDays) 
{
$fileSPLObjects =  new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($FolderName),RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY  );
foreach( $fileSPLObjects as $fullFileName => $fileSPLObject ) 
  {
  $TheFileName=$fileSPLObject->getFilename();
  $DaysOld=(int)( time()-$fileSPLObject->getMTime())/(3600*24) ); 
  if( $DaysOld  >= $NumberOfDays ) unlink( $fileSPLObject->getRealPath() );
  }
}
```